# Issue working with comparison operator

Tags: javascript

Console logging `this.byPassViewState` returns `["01"]`

if i do `this.byPassViewState === ['01']` it returns `false`

`typeof(this.byPassViewState)` retuns `object`

My question is why `this.byPassViewState` returns false ? it suppose to be `true` right ? please tell me what i'm doing wrong here

[image]

Comment: with == or === it returns false

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare 2 array with just using `==` or `===` operators. 
The easiest way to compare array is using `JSON.stringify()`.

```js
let byPassViewState = ["01"];
let compare = (JSON.stringify(byPassViewState) == JSON.stringify(["01"]) );
console.log(compare);
```

Please Reference : [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)